# implementing cyclicbarrier using threads and semaphores for specific thread types in java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, cyclicbarrier

```
public class cyclicBarrier {
    private static int n;
    private static int count;
    private static semaphore mutex;
    private static semaphore turnstile;
    private static semaphore turnstile2;

    public cyclicBarrier(int n){
        this.n = n;
        this.count = 0;
        this.mutex = new semaphore(1);
        this.turnstile = new semaphore(0);
        this.turnstile2 = new semaphore(0);
    }

    public synchronized void down() throws InterruptedException{
        this.phase1();
        this.phase2();
    }

    private synchronized void phase1() throws InterruptedException {
        this.mutex.down();
        this.count++;
        if (this.count == this.n){
            for (int i=0; i< this.n; i++){
                          this.turnstile.signal();
                    }
        }
        this.mutex.signal();
        this.turnstile.down();
    }

    private synchronized void phase2() throws InterruptedException {
        this.mutex.down();
        this.count--;
        if (this.count == 0){
            for (int i=0; i< this.n; i++){
                          this.turnstile2.signal();
                    }
        }
        this.mutex.signal();
        this.turnstile2.down();
    }
}
```

**&& here is class semaphore just in case**

```
public class semaphore{
    private int counter;

    public semaphore(int number){
        if (number > 0) {
            this.counter = number;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void signal(){
        this.counter++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void down() throws InterruptedException{
        while (this.counter <= 0){
            wait();
        }
        this.counter--;
    }
}
```

This is a code that I wrote to implement **Cyclicbarriers** using **threads**.
I took the pseudo code from the book along with the notes on deadlocks so I think its pretty much ok "there might be a bug though". The first phase is for **"arriving threads"** and the 2nd phase is for **"running threads in the critical region together"**. My question is as follows... how to change the code in order to consider specific types of threads? For instance, there are hydrogen threads and oxygen threads and I want them to execute bond() everytime there are 2 hydrogen atoms and 1 oxygen atom at the barrier. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving you an answer, I'll give you a hint.  Let me know if you want me the full answer.

First, fix your code according to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26863647/58668) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15753869/58668)—if I'm right about its flaws, that is :)

Second, imagine that we have **m** threads and a **barrier(n)** where m >= 2n, each thread doing

```
while True:
    noncritical()
    barrier.enter() # e.g. phase1()
    critical()
    barrier.leave() # e.g. phase2()
```

If you implement **enter()** and **leave()** as I have suggested, you may have **2n** threads in the critical section.  To fix this problem, I have come up with the following construct:

```
class N_At_A_Time_Barrier(n):
    fields:
        occupied = Semaphore(n)
        barrier = Barrier(n)
    method enter():
        occupied.down()
        barrier.down()
    method leave():
        occupied.up()
```

In the terminology of [*The Little book of Semaphores*](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/), **occupied** is a Multiplex.  The hint: the solution to the H2O problem is very similar to this.  My solution uses a **Barrier(1+2)** and... something else :)

(Footnote: there are more efficient ways of implementing an **N_At_A_Time_Barrier**, where each group of **n** threads has their own shared state set up by the first thread to arrive, but that's a lot more complicated and I don't think it relates to the H2O problem as neatly.)

Comment: This is only 6 years late but it's better late than never I guess. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

do you need to implement Cyclicbarriers yourself? (homework)
or can you use the JDK's implementation?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Maybe you could extend the await() method, to include your Atom kind, and add a method that tells you what atoms are waiting at the barrier, if you find the condition of having say H20, you can call a callback method, in this case bond(Atoms[] atoms)

Comment: No I have to implement it myself. :)

Comment: Thats actually a great answer but then I'd have to keep track of the array and I've got to put a mutex on it. so only one thread could add / remove from it. Thanks a lot :)